# Passing data between ViewControllers depends on tag of UIButton

Tags: swift, tableview, segue

I've `UITableView` and I'm passing selected `Item` from one `UIViewController` to another. To achieve this I have array of `Item` objects.

```
var array = [Item]()
```

for performing segue I'm passing `sender` parameter of `buttonPressed` action as `sender` of `performSegue` method.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: sender)
}
```

This button is inside `UITableViewCell` and has tag equal to `indexPath.row` which I set in TableView `cellForRowAt` data source method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
    ...
}
```

Then in ViewController's `prepare` method I downcast `sender` as `UIButton` and then I assign `selectedItem` variable in destination ViewController as `Item` from `array` with `button.tag` as index.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        let button = sender as! UIButton
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ViewController2
        destinationVC.selectedItem = array[button.tag]
    }
}
```

**Q:** This works just fine, I'm using this for a long time but I have got feeling that this isn't the right solution. Is there any better?

Comment: better solution  is don't use storyboard, use `code` or `XIB` or `mix(code and XIB)`

Comment: Nothing wrong with this. But since you are already using a `UITableView` can't you use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. If you have to click a button either you can do the way you do it or use your `UITableViewCell` class to capture the tap and use a delegate to call back you ViewController so you don't have to `addTarget` from data source delegate methods.

Comment: Your way is good, no issue with this. But you should design maximum UIs with code, not Storyboard. It's interesting to create UI using code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference is to use the delegate pattern here.

In this approach, the view controller makes itself the delegate of every tableview cell it creates. It passes the `Item` to the cell. When the button in the cell is tapped, the cell sends the `Item` back to the view controller. In this way the view controller knows which `Item` was selected and should be sent to the next view controller.

To implement, begin by declaring a variable in your tableview cell to hold the `Item`:

```
weak var item: Item?
```

In your view controller, pass the item to the cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //...
    cell.item = array[indexPath.row]
    //...
}
```

Next, declare a delegate protocol:

```
protocol ItemSelectionDelegate {
    func itemSelected(_ item: Item)
}
```

Add a variable of this type to your custom table view cell, like so:

```
weak var delegate: ItemSelectionDelegate?
```

Make the button in your tableview cell call the delegate when tapped, passing it the item:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let item = item {
        delegate?.itemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Now, make your view controller conform to this protocol:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, ..., ItemSelectionDelegate {

    func itemSelected(_ item: Item) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Make sure to set the view controller as the delegate of each cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //...
    cell.item = array[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self
    //...
}
```

Call your segue, but pass the `Item` instead of a button:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, ..., ItemSelectionDelegate {

    func itemSelected(_ item: Item) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: item)
    }
}
```

Now pass this to your next view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ViewController2
        destinationVC.selectedItem = sender as? Item
    }
}
```

This is definitely more work to set up, so use only if it makes sense to you.

Comment: Yes! This make perfect sense for me. This is solution I was looking for. As long as anybody come with better solution (if there is better solution) your answer is accepted.

Answer (score -1):

If I don't get wrong, you had to get selected index path row in `prepareForSegue`:

```
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        guard let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ViewController2 else { return }
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
        destinationVC.selectedItem = selectedIndexPath.row 
    }
```

Comment: As per the given question, he's tapping on the button so in that case, how can you get indexPath for the selected row in tableView? I will not work.

Comment: This assign just some `Int` as `selectedItem`. I’m passing `Item`. Also it doesn’t answer my question. My code works, I just need to find better solution.